# How to ignore negative values while calculating statistics in R?

Tags: r, statistics

Is it possible to ignore negative values when calculating mean, min, max and standard deviation from an R integer array? I have a 22*22 array with many negative values of -128. I want to only consider the positive values and the count of positive values when calculating the above statistics.

Comment: `min( x[x>=0] , na.rm=TRUE )`

Answer (score 2):

You can filter the values

```
#sample data
x<-c(4,1,10,-128,54,14,16,-128)

#filter helper function
isPositive <- function(x) x>=0

#calculate value(s)
mean(x)
#[1] -19.625

mean(Filter(isPositive, x))
# [1] 16.5
```

But if you have multiple -128 it sounds like that value might actually represent missing data. It may be easier to set those as NA

```
x[x==-128] <- NA
```

then you could just do

```
mean(x, na.rm=T)
# [1] 16.5
```

Comment: That is all a bit overkill, no? Why not just `mean(x[x>0])` as @BondedDust suggests? Or `mean(x[x!=-128])` if you just want to exclude one value.

Comment: I prefer the readability of Filter and the correct use of NA where appropriate. Personal preference  I guess.

Comment: Fair enough about the `NA`, but it seems a bit odd to call `Filter`, which is essentially: `x[as.logical(unlist(lapply(x,function(x) x >= 0)))]` rather than directly calling the much simpler `x[x>=0]`